# how to make a content type that ties to the user and user can only add one?

Tags: users, 8

Drupal 8

So I want users to add a actor profile or crew profile or both.
I am thinking both would be content types.  The user should only be able to add one of each and it ties to the user.

Anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating content types, I think you're better off using the profile module.

For Drupal 8 use the [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) Module

> The Profile module provides configurable user profiles.
>
> Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general
>   profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>   permissions for those. Optionally, profile forms are shown during user
>   account registration. Fields may be configured to be private - thus
>   visible only to the profile owner and administrators. Profile types
>   are displayed on the user view page, and can be configured through
>   “Manage Display” on account settings.

Formerly known as [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) in drupal 7. Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPbazpRCwP0). Perhaps it's similar in Drupal 8?